# How to write .spec file to check JRE version in Fedora 10

Tags: fedora, rpm

I am using fedora 10 linux.  I have created an RPM for my software it works fine. But I want the follwing feature
"If I install RPM it will check whether JRE 1.5 or greater is availble in that system if available then install the RPM otherwise I want to show the URL to download the JRE.

Is there anything that I have to write in my .spec file

How can I achieve this type of functionality.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I insert the following line to check for jre 1.5 or greater in your spec file
Requires:jre >= 1.5

Comment: I really find amusing the way you are answering & accepting most of your questions ...

Comment: The funniest bit is the "Hi" at the start of the answer.

Comment: Which has now been removed.